# CodedUI Test for Windows Phone 8.1 Build Failing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, coded-ui-tests

I have a simple app which I have added a CodedUI Test Project for trying out CodedUI Tesing. When I create the Test Project and create the UIMap and try to build the test project to run it, I get the following error message. The same error keeps coming in every project I build.

> Error 1   Friend access was granted to 'UITest,
>   PublicKey=002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010007d1fa57c4aed9f0a32e84aa0faefd0de9e8fd6aec8f87fb03766c834c99921eb23be79ad9d5dcc1dd9ad236132102900b723cf980957fc4e177108fc607774f29e8320e92ea05ece4e821c0a5efe8f1645c4c0c93c1ab99285d622caa652c1dfad63d745d6f2de5f17e5eaf0fc4963d261c8a12436518206dc093344d5ad293',
>   but the output assembly is named 'UITest, Version=1.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Try adding a reference to
>   'UITest,
>   PublicKey=002400000480000094000000060200000024000052534131000400000100010007d1fa57c4aed9f0a32e84aa0faefd0de9e8fd6aec8f87fb03766c834c99921eb23be79ad9d5dcc1dd9ad236132102900b723cf980957fc4e177108fc607774f29e8320e92ea05ece4e821c0a5efe8f1645c4c0c93c1ab99285d622caa652c1dfad63d745d6f2de5f17e5eaf0fc4963d261c8a12436518206dc093344d5ad293'
>   or changing the output assembly name to match.    c:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   12.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WindowsStore.UITest.Extension.dll  UITest

I have successfully build and ran a CodedUI Project a couple of days before this. It was fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have called your solution/project UITest which is also the name of one of .NET's assemblies. When that happens, .NET can get confused and throw the error you have shown.

Therefore, try renaming your solution/project to a name that isn't the same or part of an assembly in the .NET framework.